# White map but whe i apply less zoom the map appears

Tags: android, google-maps

I need put a map in a LinearLayout into another layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
 ....

     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="800dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/mapasave"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

   .......
   </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the map appears totaly white, but when i apply less zoom, the map appear, with continental size.

The code of onCreate() metod is this:

```
GoogleMap mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapasave)).getMap();
    mapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    mapa.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mapa.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,15));
    mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).
            icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

I haven't found nothing about this concrete problem. If someone know something about this, all help is welcome.

Thank you so much!

Comment: add <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" /> to manifest

Comment: i probed this code with another wifi conection and it worked fine. someone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

```
    mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,15));
```

Try to do something like

```
    mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,2));
```

The zoom value is too high I think.

Good luck

Comment: Ok! It's a good code but i need the size "15" because it has to see the building.